# Vuejs + p5js - importing library in vue-cli

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm currently developing a project in `Vue.js 2.0` (vue-cli) who need some 2D graphics and I would like to use p5js for that.

But as you know p5 don't have any node or web pack wrapper and I would like to know, I'm really just starting with webpack, if it's a least possible to import this library and build the application.

Could you point me in the right documentation for that or just tell me how to proceed such a task ?

Comment: Just include the script in your index.html file that webpack generates. Webpack will add it's scripts but you can still add your own.

Answer (score 0):

if they are both from javascript then you can use them both in different files by changing the script language.

to learn more about vue:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

to learn more about p5.js:
https://p5js.org/reference/

to learn more about changing script with the script tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the CDN link in the index.html or you could use the yarn package (it seems to be up to date).

```
yarn add p5
```

[Getting Started With Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/getting-started)